# Sort result by countries name not by countries code, Symfony2,

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using knpPaginatorBundle and I'd like to sort result by countries **name** (or by translated countries name if it's possible) not by countries **code** because the names are changed according to the locale "en, fr, de ..").

For exemple **Spain** in english begins by **S** and in french is **Espagne** and begins by **E** but the code is "ES" and it is not changeable of course. Is it possible to do this ?

This is my code:

**Twig**

```
<li class="sort-by-country {% if pagination.isSorted('t.country') %}active{% endif %}">{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country', 't.country') }}</li>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $qb = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend();

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $request->query->get('page', $page),10);


    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Travel:travel-list-view.html.twig',array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ));
}
```

**Repository**

```
//getListTravelsFrontend
public function getListTravelsFrontend()
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')
        ->addSelect('i')
        ->leftJoin('t.agence', 'a')
        ->addSelect('a')
        ->Where('t.enabled = 1');

    return $qb;

}
```

**Entity:**

```
class Travel
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
 *
 * @Assert\Country
 */
protected $country;
```

**And this is how to show name of country I use this Extension and it worsk fine**

```
namespace Project\TravelBundle\Twig;

class CountryExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('country', array($this, 'countryFilter')),
    );
}

public function countryFilter($countryCode,$locale = "en")
{
    $c = \Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames($locale);

    return array_key_exists($countryCode, $c)
        ? $c[$countryCode]
        : $countryCode;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'country_extension';
}
}
```

Comment: does your Travel class have a country name field or does it just have a country code field?

Comment: @DerickF , travel class has just a country code, is it possible to stock country name instead of country code ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to join country to your query builder. But firstly you have to describe relations between Travel and Country (you can find more about doctrine annotations mapping here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). After you set up mappings add to you query builder:

```
->leftJoin('t.country', 'c')
```

then in twig:

```
{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country', 'c.code') }}
```

Maybe it will help you: [Sorting joined table with KnpPaginatorBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452393/sorting-joined-table-with-knppaginatorbundle), [Sort over ManyToOne Relationship with KnpPaginatorBundle in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318940/sort-over-manytoone-relationship-with-knppaginatorbundle-in-symfony2).

Comment: but country is not an entity so I can't do leftJoin

Comment: Ok, and what is in t.country column then? Country code or country name?

Comment: I think you have to replace t.country with something where stored country code.

Comment: It's country code , and in the form is country type `->add('country', 'country', ...`

Comment: And? It doesn't work? Doesn't KnpPaginator generate proper link for you?

Comment: it work but knpPaginator sort result by country code and me I'd like to sort them by country name

Comment: And if in t.country is country code why do you expect it to be sorted by name? You have to put in knp paginator sortable function column name which relates to country name (if you have it stored in your database) - not to code. If you don't have such column, you have to add it. And then rewrite your pagintaror sortable head to be used this new column.

Comment: For exemple Spain in english begins by S and in french is Espagne and begins by E but the code is "ES" and it is not changeable of course.